# Basic Facts About the Cardinality of the Power Set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

If $X$ and $Y$ are nonempty sets, we define $Y^X = \{f\,|\,f\colon X\to Y\}$ and $\mathrm{card}(Y^X)=\mathrm{card} (Y)^{\mathrm{card}(X)}$.

1. Show that the above definition is independent on the sets
   representing cardinal numbers, that is, if $X'$ and $Y'$ are sets
   with the same cardinality as $X$ and $Y$, respectively, then
   $\mathrm{card}(Y)^{\mathrm{card}(X)} =
       \mathrm{card}(Y')^{\mathrm{card}(X')}$.
2. Prove that $1^c = 1$ and
   $c^1 = c$, where $c$ is a cardinal number.

Comment: sorry.. i don't know how to edit here.

Comment: Did you mean to say that $X$ and $Y$ should be nonempty sets? What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: yes. i'm going to edit it.

Comment: i'm not stuck. i don't know how to start it.

Answer (score 1):

For 1, saying $X'$ has the same cardinality as $X$ means there is a bijection between them.  You are expected to find a bijection between $Y^X$ and $Y'^{X'}$ given that there is one between each of the basic pairs.

For 2, you are expected to find an explicit bijection between the set of functions on the left and the cardinal number on the right.